# How to iterate over to rightmost leaf in a function

Tags: python, class

So I have this code:

```
def min_node(self):
        while self.right != None:
            self.data = self.right

        return self.data
```

And I want it to keep iterating to the right until the next right is None, but for some reason self.right just stays the same value so the while loops goes on forever. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you have a loop with some termination condition that depends on a value, but you never change that value inside the loop's block, you get an infinite loop.

Comment: Is there a way where I can keep iterating over to the right until I reach the last leaf so that the loop ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about recursion?

```
def min_node(self):
        if self.right is None:
            return self.data
        return self.right.min_node()
```

Or iteratively?

```
def min_node(self):
    result = self
    while result.right is not None:
        result = result.right
    return result.data
```

Comment: I tried both and got errors. Here's my full code: https://pastebin.com/FPrDpinP. What I want to do is get the value of the rightmost leaf and put it inside a variable. (Line 64). But my min_node keeps return None.

Comment: Well, it is still possible to get `None` out of that min_node function. Especially if `self.data is None` for some nodes. Actually both of my suggested implementations return `None` only in the case that `None` is `.data` of some instance of your class. Have you tried to use assertions to ensure that `self.data` must not be `None`?

Comment: So I tried printing self.data to see what is going on in the min_node function and it seems to work correctly. When self.data = 6, self.right is None and it returns 6, but I think because it is a recursion, the 6 doesn't go anywhere so when it returns back to line 64 when I called the function, it returns None instead of 6.

Comment: you are missing a `return` in line 34. It should read `return self.right.min_node()`. Hope that fixes your problem.

Comment: I added it in and it just kept iterating over and over again. I feel like this might have been easier if I made my remove method a standalone function instead of being part of my binary tree class, but I have spent way too much time to give up on it lol.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the code working, not really sure what I did different to get it to work lol, but the iterative method worked for me.